# Azure VS2019 designing and creating a Cosmo DB instance

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using VS2019 to create an Azure Cloud App.  I want to create a Cosmo DB instance and do some round-trip development.   Normally I would just jump into the Azure portal and create the appropriate resources.

This time I need to automate the process, so I have a Resource project in VS2019 and I would like to specify the appropriate artifacts for deployment.   When I select 'Add Resource' in visual studio, I can't see anything for Cosmo DB - just SQL Server and MySQL.

The approach that I have taken is to manually create a resource group with appropriate DB and assets, download the ARM template and publish from VS.

The bit that I need to figure out now, is how to add a schema, containers and pre-load data into the result (I am more familiar with SSDT with SQL Server and post deployment scripts).

The goal is to get a round-trip deployment to a new environment with appropriate test data from Visual Studio (sans CI pipelines).

Regards.

Comment: What is the ask here? It is not very clear from above.

Comment: Sorry, this is more Azure related.    When one creates a visual studio Resource Group project for Azure, one can add a SQL Server template to the project.  On publish, the Azure SQL Database instance is stood up and accessible using SSDT.   What I was looking for is a similar template for Cosmo DB.